# TemplateColumn button command binding not working in Syncfusion DataGrid

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, syncfusion

I'm using Syncfusion's datagrid in a `UWP` project. Everything works fine except command binding of button inside a `GridTemplateColumn`. What could be the issue ?

***XAML***

```
<my:GridTemplateColumn MappingName="Actions" HeaderText="Actions"
                       AllowFiltering="False">
    <my:GridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="0"  HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Button  VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="40" Content="Delete"   
                         my:FocusManagerHelper.FocusedElement="True"
                              Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.RemoveBtnCommand}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </my:GridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</my:GridTemplateColumn>
```

***View Model***

```
public ICommand RemoveBtnCommand { get; }
public HRMDepartmentsViewModel()
{
    IsActive = true;
    RemoveBtnCommand = new AsyncRelayCommand(CommandRemoveBtnClickedExecute);
}
private async Task CommandRemoveBtnClickedExecute()
{
  // never executed-- code here 
}
```

***What else i've tried***
I tried to use `Binding` instead if `x:Bind` but it also doesn't work

```
Command="{Binding Path=RemoveBtnCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"
```

***Observation***

If i don't use `Command` and use `Click` event binding it works.

```
<my:GridTemplateColumn MappingName="Actions" HeaderText="Actions"
                       AllowFiltering="False">
    <my:GridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="0"  HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Button  VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="40" Content="Delete"
                         Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.ButtonBase_OnClick}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </my:GridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</my:GridTemplateColumn>
```

***View Model***

```
public void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // It gets called
}
```

Comment: https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/5910/how-to-pass-row-data-as-parameter-to-the-command-in-viewmodel-when-clicking-the-button-in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> TemplateColumn button command binding not working in Syncfusion DataGrid

I'm afraid you can't bind the button command in the `DataTemplate` like above, because command will not find correct `DataContext`. If you want to bind the ViewModel's `RemoveBtnCommand`, you need get root DataContext then direct to RemoveBtnCommand property. For more please refer the following code.

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel x:Name="ViewModel" />
</Page.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Custom:SfDataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}">
        <Custom:SfDataGrid.Columns>
            <Custom:GridTemplateColumn
                AllowFiltering="False"
                HeaderText="Actions"
                MappingName="Actions"
                >
                <Custom:GridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            Orientation="Horizontal"
                            Spacing="0"
                            >
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                            <Button
                                Width="40"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                Custom:FocusManagerHelper.FocusedElement="True"
                                Command="{Binding ElementName=MyDataGrid, Path=DataContext.RemoveBtnCommand}"
                                Content="Delete"
                                />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Custom:GridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </Custom:GridTemplateColumn>
        </Custom:SfDataGrid.Columns>
    </Custom:SfDataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your requirement by pass the row information as a parameter to the command in ViewModel when clicking a button in TemplateColumn by passing the CommandParameter. Please refer the below KB documentation for more details reference,

KB Link:https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/5910/how-to-pass-row-data-as-parameter-to-the-command-in-viewmodel-when-clicking-the-button-in

Regards,

Vijayarasan S